# this.axios.post(url, dataObject) only return 0

Tags: vue.js, axios

i have a little vuejs app connected with wordpress.

In my wordpress controller i will send a json response back to my the vue app.

```
this.axios.post(ajaxurl, qs.stringify({
    action: 'form_handler',
    form: this.form,
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
}))
.then(function(response) {
    console.log('success')
    console.log(response)
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log('error')
    console.log(error)
})
```

The PHP works without any problems and return the right json.

```
return json_encode(['status': 200, 'user_id': '123kl-234op-12390']);
```

But when i check the ajax response i will only show data: 0

```
{data: 0, status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers:
```

How do i pass data to my vue app? In any every case it show the value 0.

I want to get my user id as data response

```
{data: { status: 200, user_id: '123kl-234op-12390' }, status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers:
```

Comment: your data send in php should not be `json_encode(['status'=> 200, 'user_id'=> '123kl-234op-12390']);`?

Comment: my ajax function return true or false.. but in both cases i only get "0" in my javascript response. i want to know how i can pass data from php to the javascript response i use this.axios.post

Comment: Hello @hans-felix-ramos, my solution was to "echo" the array.. with "return" it doesn't work.. so instead of `return json_encode($array);` i will use `echo json_encode($array);` now